# Why does the Enter Key disregards Tab Index?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, tabindex

Here's my cshtml file:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc;
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
@using System;
@using System.Data;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Text;

@model My.Name.Space.Models.SomeObject

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Title";
    Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? null : "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div id="dv3" class="scrollarea">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("dv3", "", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { id = "frmP3" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div>
            @(Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field1, new { id = "txt1", @tabIndex = "1" }))
            @(Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field11, new { id = "txt11", @tabIndex = "11" }))
            @(Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field21, new { id = "txt21", @tabIndex = "21" }))
            <br /><br />
            @(Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field2, new { id = "txt2", @tabIndex = "2" }))
            @(Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field12, new { id = "txt12", @tabIndex = "12" }))
            @(Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field22, new { id = "txt22", @tabIndex = "22" }))
            <br /><br />
            @(Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field3, new { id = "txt3", @tabIndex = "3" }))
            @(Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field13, new { id = "txt13", @tabIndex = "13" }))
            @(Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field23, new { id = "txt23", @tabIndex = "23" }))
            <br /><br />
            @(Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field4, new { id = "txt4", @tabIndex = "4" }))
            @(Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field14, new { id = "txt14", @tabIndex = "14" }))
            @(Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field24, new { id = "txt24", @tabIndex = "24" }))
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

My controller is equally simple:

```
public ActionResult View3()
{
    return View(base.GetViewPath("3"), new SomeObject());
}
```

I run the application and navigate to this page then set focus to `txt1`. When I press `Tab` the focus changes from `txt1` to `txt2`. Perfect.

If I press `Enter`, focus changes from `txt1` to `txt11`. Incorrect. It is supposed to go to the the control with the next closest tab index.

Why does `Enter` not follow the same order as `Tab`?

Comment: No its not. Pressing the Enter key is supposed to submit the form but you don't appear to have a submit button (you might also be interested in [The Enter Key should Submit Forms, Stop Suppressing it](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/01/01/enter-should-submit-forms-stop-messing-with-that/)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Trust me, I really really wish we could just tell our users, "THAT'S WHAT THE TAB KEY IS FOR". Literally no one in my company knew you could hit Enter to change focus in our software, so none of us know where this behavior is coming from. But apparently our users were aware of it. And it suddenly broke with a release and all of our users are super salty that Enter no longer works as they expect it to.